# How to bind third party module using webpack?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, webpack, typing

I am using ng2-bs3-modal module to open modal popup. But when I run project using visual studio 2015, it giving me few errors. Most of them are indicating "Cannot find name 'Promise'". I have searched and I got vague idea about binding this module using webpack.

Comment: update your post with the code which causes you trouble

Answer (score 0):

Usually that indicates missing typings. Try adding this to `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.json:

```
"lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
```

Comment: Not working. Actually I do not get any error in console. But when I build solution in VS2015.